# Targeting the parent element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have made a dropdown menu that uses tabs to display the specific content for each menu item.

This is the link to the jQuery tutorial I used for the tabbing functionality:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs

I have modified the code to suit my needs, but am having trouble finding a way to change the element which the 'active' class is applied too. For CSS styling reasons I want the 'active' class to be applied to the parent `<li>` of the `<a>` which it is currently being added too.

I have tried various solutions including the `.parent();` method to no avail. Any advice here would be much appreciated.

Here's a quick snippet of the code that handles adding the class:

```
// Keep track of which tab is active and it's associated content
var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('li.activate-dropdown a');

// If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
$active = $($links.filter('[rel="'+location.hash+'"]')[0]);
$active.addClass('active');
$content = $($active.attr('rel'));
```

**EDIT:**
Example live code - http://jsfiddle.net/jgfg7/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.closest('li')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) when you are removing or adding the class to `$active`.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgfg7/4/

Answer (score 0):

If your code works with the `<a>` element, this should work for the parent:

```
// Keep track of which tab is active and it's associated content
var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('li.activate-dropdown a');

// If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
$active = $($links.filter('[rel="'+location.hash+'"]')[0]);
$active.parent().addClass('active');
$content = $($active.attr('rel'));
```

Comment: I have already tried using the .parent() method, but I doesn't seem to work. The 'active' is still being applied to the a tag. Here is a quick Fiddle I've done up with the entire working code - http://jsfiddle.net/jgfg7/3/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$active.parents("li").addClass('active');
```

Comment: `.closest()` would be much better than `.parents()`.